# How shall I understand the synopsis of this command?

Tags: man, syntax, nix

https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/command-ref/nix-shell.html

> **Synopsis**
>
> nix-shell [--arg name value] [--argstr name value] [{--attr | -A}
> attrPath] [--command cmd] [--run cmd] [--exclude regexp] [--pure]
> [--keep name] {{--packages | -p} {packages | expressions} … | [path]}

and

> **Examples**
>
> ```
> $ nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' --attr pan
> ```

What role in its synopsis does `'<nixpkgs>'`  play?

Is it `path`? If yes,

- does `path` specify the package collection from which the package specified after `--attr` comes?
- why isn't it specified at the end of the command?